# Regex that satisfies multiple criteria

Tags: regex

I need to come up with a regular expression with flavor PCRE. It must be a regular expression <

I want to grab all lines of text that end in a newline character up until I encounter `<zz>` where zz is a digit enclosed in '`<`' and '`>`'.

e.g.

```
111a z
222 aset
333 //+
12 <zz> 11
abc
def
```

It would need to capture "`111a z`", "`222 aset`", "`333 //+`" in this case [and nothing else].
Right now I have `^(?!.*<zz>)[^\n]+(?=\n)` but it's pretty far off from what it needs to be.

For clarification purposes, the regex I was using shows `<zz>`, but definitely looking for a digit enclosed in angle brackets.

Would really appreciate some help.

**Edit**

This is /really/ difficult for me, because at least one of the answers looks like it does the job. I'll try to mark one... Thank you, everyone.

Comment: You say 'where zz is a digit enclosed in [angle brackets]', but your example has literal `<zz>` in there - so which is it? Also, is what you're really saying you want every complete line before the first line that contains `<zz>` or `<\d+>` (whichever is the case)?

Comment: You basically need the first match from this: `"^((?!<\\d+>).)*$"` with `PCRE_DOTALL` and `PCRE_MULTILINE`. But it's been answered before, I'll vote to close with link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Comment: Which is it - digit enclosed in angle brackets. And yes.

Comment: Haven't spent enough time to distill information from the topics you linked, but at a high level it's probably similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could repeat matching all lines including a Unicode newline sequence while the `<\d+>` pattern does not occur in the line.

```
\A(?:(?!.*<\d+>).*\R)+
```

**Explanation**

- `\A` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?!.*<\d+>)` Negative lookahead, assert that the pattern `<\d+>` does not occur
  - `.*\R` Match any char except a newline followed by matching a Unicode newline sequence
- `)+` Close the non capturing group, and repeat it 1+ times to match at least a single line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XhcgGs/1)

---

If the `<\d+>` has to be present, you could assert that with a positive lookahead at the end

```
\A(?:(?!.*<\d+>).*\R)+(?=.*<\d+>)
```

Comment: This is actually more in line with what I described than one of the other answers here. Sadly, I didn't do an adequate job describing what I needed. Was an oversight on my part. Oddly, an answer that failed to address one of the requirements in full works for my use case better.

Comment: Charlie Armstrong's answer actually worked for my use case better, but only because I failed to describe the problem adequately. Your answer along with one other were probably better. I don't really have enough knowledge about which is better in terms of performance, so I just went ahead and marked one that seemed to match.

Comment: @aaaa Sure, can you add the example data that you have to a https://regex101.com/ link, save and share the link here in the comments and specify what should and should not be matched.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/2hO0Tn/1 - So, this is almost what I want. I just don't want it to fail on the first instance of seeing a digit enclosed in angle brackets. Would you perhaps know how to tweak this one? It's tantalizingly close.

Comment: @aaaa So the logic right now of the pattern is: match the whole line followed by a newline if what is on the right contains `<\d+>`. And that `what is on the right` part can be on any line as `[\s\S]` matches any char including a newline. It does not match the last line, as that line actually contains `<00>` What should the expected match be?

Comment: In the very first line where it says, `000 <00date=0000-00-00,time=00:00:00,devname="",devid="",logid="",type="",subtype="",level="",vd="",eventtime=,srcip=000.00`, if that were to say, " `000 <00>date=...` I would want that line matched since it's only the first instance of it.

Where Cary Swoveland says, "I have assumed that the text may have more than one line that contains one or digits bracketed in '<' and '>', and that those lines are not themselves to be matched." is correct. Those lines are not to be matched except for the first instance of it.

Comment: @aaaa If this is just about the first line, you could optionally match it https://regex101.com/r/Hxg3oN/1

Comment: I'll provide another example: https://regex101.com/r/4DJToA/2 -- In this case, `zzadsgas` is not correct. It should have stopped matching things after `<1>`, but it should have grabbed the first line as if it were "`000 <0date=0000-00-00,time=00:00:00,devname="",devid="",logid="",type="",subtype="",level="",vd="",eventtime=,srcip=000.00.00.000,srcp`".

Comment: With the current logic, is will match `zzadsgas` Why should it not match it? That is exactly what the positive lookahead is doing, matching the whole line as what is somewhere on the right is `<\d+>` Should `<\d+>` occur only once and then stop the match?

Comment: At a high level, I'm trying to simply get lines from the first "event" only. An event starts with a digit enclosed in angle brackets and ends with a newline. The problem is that some events have newline characters in the middle of them. I'm trying to come up with a regular expression to tackle this problem. https://regex101.com/r/21ldPF/1 - This shows why it's failing. It grabbed the second event.

Comment: To get the first one only, you could omit the global flag and grab all the following lines that do not contain the digit pattern.`^.*<\d+>.*(?:\r?\n(?!.*<\d+>).*)*` https://regex101.com/r/ACH0q4/1

Comment: I should explain. I'm working with https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html. I sadly cannot just disable the global flag that I'm aware of. My use case probably demands that.

Comment: Is there any way that you know of that I could return the first match without omitting that flag or perhaps something analagous? I thought maybe `\1` might work, but cannot figure out how to integrate it.

Comment: I have knowledge of logstash unfortunately. You could give this a try `\A.*<\d+>.*(?:\r?\n(?!.*<\d+>).*)*` I read the readme here, and is it not supposed to match multiple values? https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-codec-multiline/blob/master/docs/index.asciidoc

Comment: I wasn't really expecting you to [or even distill information from it for that matter], I just was placing the link there to explain the higher level problem that I'm trying to solve. I think it is supposed to match multiple. I think that it's global by default with the plugin I'm using. Though, there may be a way around that. I'm just trying everything I can to solve this problem. I will attempt the expression you sent in a second.

Comment: That may have actually solved the problem. I can't even begin to thank you enough if that was it. I need to do more rigorous testing, but could you explain the small change that you made?

Comment: I used `\A` instead of `^` See this page for more info about the anchors https://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#A

Comment: Thank you, will check it out.

Comment: I just want to say thank you for everything you've helped with. I haven't found any problems with what you provided and have learned a lot from this whole process.

Comment: Could we go to chat briefly? I sadly have one more restriction that I was unaware of at the time. I've tried fixing it myself, but still struggling. It turns out the "events" are separated by escaped newline characters.

I can share what I've come up with so far if it would help. @The fourth bird

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215772/discussion-between-aaaa-and-the-fourth-bird).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using a negative lookahead, but I think you want a positive lookahead.  This lets you only match the line if you see the `<zz>` in a lookahead.  I would solve the problem using something like this:

```
^.*(?=.*(?:\n.*)*<\d+>)\n
```

- `^` Anchors match to beginning of line (like yours)
- `.*` Matches all the characters it can.  In this case it matches the whole line because it has to satisfy the `\n` at the end.
- `(?=...)` Performs a positive lookahead (makes sure the string exists somewhere ahead)
- `.*(?:\n.*)*` Allows any number of characters on any number of lines
- `<\d+>` Only matches one or more digits enclosed in angle brackets
- `\n` ensures that there is a newline at the end of the line.

Comment: Hey, Charlie Armstrong. Oddly your answer actually worked for my use case better. I think the answers from Cary Swoveland and The fourth bird were more in line with how I described the problem, but this was invaluable to me nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that the text may have more than one line that contains one or digits bracketed in `'<'` and `'>'`, and that those lines are not themselves to be matched.

You can use the following expression to match the lines of interest.

```
^(?!.*<\d+>).*\r?\n(?=[\s\S]*?<\d+>)
```

[PCRE Demo](https://regex101.com/r/w3Mwl0/2/)

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^           match beginning of line
(?!         begin negative lookahead (prevent matching line with '<12>'
  .*        match 0+ characters other than newlines
   <\d+>    match '<', 1+ digits, '>'
)           end negative lookahead
.*          match 0+ characters other than newlines
\r?\n       match newline optionally preceded by '\r'
(?=         begin positive lookahead
  [\s\S]*?  match 0+ characters (incl. newlines), non-greedily
  <\d+>     match '<', 1+ digits, '>' 
)           end positive lookahead
```

`'\r'`, a carriage return, will be present if the file was produced when using the Windows operating system.

Comment: This is actually more in line with what I described than one of the other answers here. Sadly, I didn't do an adequate job describing what I needed. Was an oversight on my part. Oddly, an answer that failed to address one of the requirements in full works for my use case better.

Comment: If your question was not clear you should edit to make it clear, even now that you’ve selected an answer. You owe that to current and future readers. One thing specifically is that you need to fix your example to address @Grismar’s comment. That leaps out for everybody who reads your question.

Comment: The reason I didn't edit it was because you all did answer it as it was posed and correctly. I didn't accept Charlie Armstrong's answer as it didn't cover the case where it started with a digit enclosed in angle brackets. I will however address Grismar's comment; I agree with you, improves readability.

Comment: Hey,

Struggling a bit.

regex101.com/r/2hO0Tn/1 - So, this is almost what I want. I just don't want it to fail on the first instance of seeing a digit enclosed in angle brackets. Would you perhaps know how to tweak this one? It's tantalizingly close